# как передать параметры конструктору?

Tags: javascript

Когда конструктор внутри функции, все работает:

```
markers[0].id = 0;
markers[0].addListener('click', function() {
new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString[this.id]}).open(map, this);
});
```

Как только я конструктор выношу наружу - перестает работать!

```
markers[0].id = 0;
markers[0].addListener('click', function() {
infowindow.open(map, this);
});

infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString[this.id]
});
```

Понятно, что дело в `[this.id]`, но как передать `markers[0].id` в `contentString`? Такая запись `contentString[markers[0].id]` конечно работает, но меня не устраивает, т.к. в рабочем коде у меня не ноль, а счетчик `markers[i].id`

Comment: `infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString[markers[0].id]
});`

Comment: здесь упрощенный код, а на сайте `markers[i].id` поэтому я не могу явно прописать ключ у markers  и использую this